# Можно ли использовать Jivosite как посредник?

Tags: chat

Всем привет. Нужно помощь в реализации такой идеи. Возможно ли использовать jivosite как посредник т.е У нас уже есть готовый клиентский приложения для обращения к операторам а сторону оператора хочется сделать с помощью jivosite но со своими таблицами и базы данных. Возможно ли это. Или есть другие сервисы которые предлагают такой возможности

Comment: Этот вопрос нужно задавать непосредственно jivosite.

Comment: 1. это не безопасно 2. это глупо со стороны jivosite. Вроде как у них есть API какое-то, но не уверен. большего Вам не предоставят.

Comment: А есть ли какие нибудь другие средства для реализации такого проекта